# (No such column).. But, it's there

Tags: sqlite, web-sql

Here's my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message_threads (
    thread_id integer primary key autoincrement NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL, 
    last_checked timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    last_updated timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
    message_id integer primary key autoincrement NOT NULL,
    thread_id integer NOT NULL,message_type integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    message_content varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    message_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    sent integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Could not prepare statement (1 no such column: m.message_date)
```

Here's the query that I'm using (This query works in MySQL, as I tested it in PHPMyAdmin with a dummy table)

```
SELECT * FROM messages m, message_threads t
    WHERE m.thread_id = t.thread_id
    ORDER BY t.last_updated, t.thread_id, m.message_date;
```

I'm using WebSQL (which I think is SQLite)

FULL WebSQL CODE

```
    $rootScope.database = openDatabase('application.db', '1.0', 'Application database', 1024 * 1024);
    $rootScope.database.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message_threads (thread_id integer primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, user_id integer NOT NULL, last_checked timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', last_updated timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);");
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (message_id integer primary key autoincrement NOT NULL,thread_id integer NOT NULL,message_type integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',message_content varchar(500) NOT NULL, message_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, sent integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0');");

    });

    // Empty messages/threads for testing purposes
    $rootScope.database.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM messages;");
        tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM message_threads;");
    });

    $rootScope.database.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO message_threads (user_id) VALUES (?);", [0]);
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO messages (thread_id, message_content, sent) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", [1, "How are you doing?", 1]);
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO messages (thread_id, message_content) VALUES (?, ?);", [1, "Good you?"]);
    });

    $rootScope.database.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM messages m, message_threads t WHERE m.thread_id = t.thread_id ORDER BY t.last_updated, t.thread_id, m.message_date", [], function(tx, rs) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rs));
        }, function(tx, err) {
            alert("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    });
```

I should add that the query works fine using DBBrowser for SQLite.

Comment: SQLite is not a local version of MySQL.

Comment: @Uueerdo - Removed MySQL tag.

Comment: As you are not testing the query against the same database, make sure the websql/sqlite on does indeed have those fields. I am not familiar enough with sqlite to advise any better than that.

Comment: What returns this query? `SELECT m.message_date FROM messages m, message_threads t
    WHERE m.thread_id = t.thread_id
    ORDER BY t.last_updated, t.thread_id;`

Comment: @C1sc0 - Same error.

Comment: @Uueerdo - I have no way to test against the database that I'm aware of, nor do I even know where the database is being stored on my application. (Web app)

Comment: Hmm, `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='messages';` this will return the create table SQL statement is the same as yours?

Comment: @C1sc0 - "Failed to read the 'insertId' property from 'SQLResultSet': The query didn't result in any rows being added."

I added my full WebSQL code to the question

Comment: Note: I downloaded DB Browser, created a database and used the data (in SQLite) and the query returns expected results. Still not working in WebSQL

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your database has an older version of the table without the column.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` only creates a new table with the given specification if a table by the same *name* does not exist. It does nothing to make sure the columns are there.

To fix it, either remove your database file, or use `DROP TABLE` to get rid of your old tables before recreating them.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fresh new sqlite database and tested both of your create queries using the plain command line sqlite.exe version 3.8.0.2 on windows 7. There were no errors.

Then I have used SQLiteStudio Version 3.0.6 and entered some dummy data and executed your select query. Again no issues.

The tools that I have used can only deal with sqlite. Therefore, it seems to me that there are some configuration issues with your tools.